# AngularJS : Jasmine Unit Testing Promise Complications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-promise

I am new to AngularJS testing with Jasmine.

I have a service named pageService which relies on another services named fileLoader.

Within my page service I have the following code:

```
   service.getPageInformation = function (pageName){
      var defer = $q.defer();

      fileLoader.getFile("pageInformation")
        .then(function (res) {
          for(var i = 0 ; i < res.length ; i++){
            if(res[i].name == pageName)
              defer.resolve(res[i]);
          }
          defer.reject("No Page found");
         ;
        }, function (err) {
          defer.reject(err);
        });

      return defer.promise;
    };
```

Which tries to get a file and does some logic on retrieval.

The get file method is shown below.

```
  fileLoader.getFile = function(name){
      var defer = $q.defer();

      $http.get("data/" + name + ".json")
        .success(function(res){
          defer.resolve(res);
        })
        .error(function(err,status){
          defer.reject(err);
        });


      return defer.promise;
    }
```

To unit test the page service I have tried spying, mocking, decorating the file loader and I just can't get a simple test to work.

Can someone help me create a basic test?

Thanks

Comment: check this guide https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I spy on an Angular promise chain using Jasmine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633028/how-do-i-spy-on-an-angular-promise-chain-using-jasmine)